# Convert json formatted Chrome bookmark file into html

Tags: google-chrome

How can I convert json formatted bookmarks file (taken from /Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks) into an bookmarks html file so Google Chrome can import it?

Comment: did you handle it out?

Comment: @Mr.P I couldn't figure it out. So whenever I need to use a bookmark, I copy url from json file into chrome url window. :(

Comment: I've found out solution ... because Chrome creates many accounts, you just need to load the bookmark file into right one :) (so store them in all accounts directories) .. this helped me .. to identify what account are u using just create one bookmark a look for the keyword :)

Comment: @Mr.P do you mean you copied the files over into the current chrome installs' directory, like 2 'bookmarks' files are found in the directory? Or did you concatenate the files? Because I was thinking about doing this but there is a checksum value within the bookmarks file

Answer (score 4):

##### Finally i found it

**Step 1:**  Goto **Run** --> enter - **appdata** to navigate to this folder

**Step 2:** You Needs to take backup/copy of your old bookmarks and keep it one place

[image]

**Step 3 :** then you need to navigate to below folder, you can find many profiles of yours.

Navigate to the needed gmail account profile which has your display pic or profile pic

[identify the account you want to import bookmarks]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Go back to the profile 12 [the account which i want to see the bookmarks]**

**Then replace your old bookmark file here[step 2:which you taken backup bookmark file]**

[image]

**Boooooom! just restart chrome**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This has more or less been answered in comments by @Mr.P, but let me formalise:

In my example I have a current (OS root) drive called `C:\\`. I have a storage drive of `F:\\` which has a previous install of Chrome on it which I want to retrieve the bookmarks from.

I did this in Powershell but you could easily do it in *file explorer* you would just need to either enter the path to `<drive_name>:\\users\<account_name>\appdata` manually/show hidden folders.

1. close all instances of Chrome currently running (maybe check in the process monitor to ensure all processes terminated).
2. navigate to `<storage_drive_letter>:\\users\<account_name>\appdata\local\google\chrome\default`.
3. On PowerShell you would select the previous install bookmarks file by entering `$books = Get-Item bookmarks`. On file explorer you would 'cut'
4. `cd <os_drive_letter>:\\users\<account_name>\appdata\local\google\chrome\default` or navigate to this path on file explorer
5. `mv $books .` or paste file
6. open up Chrome again and check the bookmarks: they should be visible all together.
7. [optional] If you're brave close all Chrome windows once again (potentially save both files somewhere else before you do this) delete all files with 'bookmarks' at the start (you can use `gci | where {$_.name -like "bookmarks"} | rm`) then reopen the browser. In your filesystem Chrome should have automatically regenerated the bookmarks into one file.

If this doesn't work for other people let me know

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to make Chrome and Firefox restore my bookmarks from the Bookmarks or Bookmarks.bak json files.
But I found this really helpful online tool to convert those json files to an HTML file that you can then just import via the top-right corner in the chrome://bookmarks/ screen:

https://rongjiecomputer.github.io/chrome/bookmark-recovery/#windows

Comment: THANK YOU MAN! You literally saved me :)

Answer (score 1):

If for whatever reason, you only have the JSON output of the Chrome bookmarks file, don't sweat it. Chrome will export bookmarks as HTML and import as HTML. But, sometimes you don't have the luxury of exporting from Chrome because of some issue with your Windows installation. But, you're resourceful and managed to at least get access to your Windows filesystem and backed up your Chrome bookmarks file. But, now how do you import it to Chrome on a working computer without it being in HTML format?

On Windows (this was tested on Win 10), all you have to do is Show Hidden Files and Folders and then paste and overwrite the Bookmarks file at:

C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Don't run around in circles trying to convert JSON to HTML if you have a Windows computer. I'm not sure about Mac and Linux, but I'd bet it would work similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Folder location of bookmark (on February 2021)

- Chrome: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
- Edge: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default

Note: "Default" could be something else (e.g. Profile 1) if you are not currently logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this harder than it is.  Save the JASON bookmark.file, first. Go to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` to save the Bookmark.file somewhere on your computer. Then uninstall the browser (Chrome, for example). Make sure you check the box to remove all history, etc. before you click on Uninstall.

Reinstall the browser, then overwrite the Bookmark.file in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

DONE! Bookmarks restored. No need to save bookmark.file or convert it to an HTML file for restoral. Just overwrite the bookmark.file with the one you saved before uninstall of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about modifying existing programs, or overwriting any other bookmarks you've currently got, then I found the following easiest:

1. Install a portable version of Chrome, for example from [portableapps.com](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable)
2. Navigate to `App\DefaultData\profile\Default` inside the install directory
3. Replace the `Bookmarks` file with your json file
4. Launch Chrome Portable, and export the bookmarks as html
5. Delete Chrome Portable

Answer (score 0):

In my case It was not needed to change the files format, just moved the files to the right place.

I moved bookmarks from chromium to google chrome. For some reason chromium coldn't export files.

Location for chromium in my machine was:
/home/user/.config/google-chrome/Default/

The files to copy are:
/home/user-name/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Bookmarks
/home/user-name/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Bookmarks.bak

Destination for chrome was:
/home/mariano/.config/google-chrome/Default/

so I copy this files to destination and restart the browser and it worked

In the new

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem with opera. I simply copy pasted that json file into new location of new installation.

Answer (score -2):

Just drag the .json to opened firefox window and the run bookmarklet 
(create new bookmark, enter code in location)
CODE: SELECT ALL
javascript:(function(){var E=document.getElementsByTagName('PRE')[0],T=E.innerHTML,i=0,r1,r2;t=new Array();while(/("uri":"([^"]*)")/g.exec(T)){r1=RegExp.$1;r2=RegExp.$2;if(/^https?:/.exec(r2)){t[i++]='['+(i)+']:'+r2+'</a>';}}with(window.open().document){for(i=0;t[i];i++)write(t[i]+'
');close();}})();
Thanks to dickvl
Clickable links result
Save webpage complete will save .htm

Save .json to desktop, drag browser window smaller from lower right edge till you can drag the .json into opened window., doubleclick titlebar to restore browser full size. In the tab that opens with .json data, click the bookmarklet. Another tab should open with links. You can save as .htm by right click "save page as" web page complete.

Anywhere in the opened window, like dragging a shortcut or html, it'll open

You can also do File > Open File > browse to .json > open

Using JSON

Backup your bookmarks as a JSON file.
Delete the bookmarks you do not want.
Export the ones you do want as an HTML file
Restore your bookmarks with the JSON file
To add mor in the JSON file in a text editor.
Create rows by finding and replacing ',{"title' with 'return{"title' (Don't type the single quotes and, in the replace field, use the appropriate substitute for return: ¶ or \r, for example. My search looked like this: Find: ,{"title Replace: \r,{"title Replace All gave me rows instead of a continuous stream of text.
Save the file as text and open it in a spreadsheet. Each bookmark will have its own row. The site name, URLs, and other data are in columns.
Create a bookmark by copying the URL, pasting it into Firefox, and going to the website.
Drag the URL from the toolbar to the desired location in the sidebar. Change the bookmark title if you don't like the website-assigned title.
Repeat as needed.